# Null value coming in my custom reader in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am having a spring batch process that reads the value from a table and writes it to a custom writer.
I am using spring scheduler to execute the job. Below is my configuration for spring scheduler. 
But I am getting null values in the reader. I do not see any error in the log, my job just runs fine but the value of month is coming as null. (Yet to use my param value in my query so it works for the generic query.)

My Scheduler:

```
JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .addString("date", "07-12-2017") // will be from a variable
                    .addString("month", "june")      // will be from a variable
                    .toJobParameters();

JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
```

My Reader :

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<Bill> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters[month]}") String month) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("*****************************");
    System.out.println("month ::::::: "+month);
    System.out.println("*****************************"); 

    // My awesome database query here, where I will be using month.
```

The above month is coming as null.

My Batch Configuration :

```
 @Bean
public Job CreateBillJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) throws Exception {

    return jobBuilderFactory.get("createBill")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(step1())
            .end()
            .build();
}

private static final String OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION = null;

@Bean
public Step step1() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Bill, Bill> chunk(500)
            .reader(billDataReader.reader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(fileWriter)
            .build();
}
```

Any help on this is really appreciated. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is a single quote missing around `month` , `@Value("#{jobParameters['month']}"`  instead of `@Value("#{jobParameters[month]}"`

Comment: Thank you @SabirKhan, for the reply. I tried but still not working, the same null is coming.

Comment: I know this looks strange, but I moved the reader back to my Batch Configuration file from its individual file and it worked. Is this right approach, I am not sure.